# Saving coordinates of path in recursive maze solver?

Tags: c++, recursion, coordinates, maze

I have a recursive maze solver algorithm that can successfully work its way through the maze. The only problem is that I can not find a way to save the shortest path between the starting point and the ending point. How would I save the coordinates of the shortest path?

This is the recursive function

```
void Solve_Maze(int coorx,int coory) {
    if((coorx>=0)&&(coorx<l)&&(coory>=0)&&(coory<w)) {
        if((Map[coorx][coory]==Start)||(Map[coorx][coory]==path)) {
            Map[coorx][coory]=visited;
            Solve_Maze(coorx+1,coory);
            Solve_Maze(coorx-1,coory);
            Solve_Maze(coorx,coory+1);
            Solve_Maze(coorx,coory-1);
        }else if(Map[coorx][coory]==End) {
            delete Map;
            Solved=true;
        }
    }
}
```

After adding a vector to store the coordinates I got this output

```
(1,2)
(2,2)
(3,2)
(4,2)
(5,2)
(6,2)
(7,2)
(8,2)
(9,2)
(7,3)
(7,4)
(7,5)
(7,6)
(8,6)
(8,7)
(9,7)
(10,7)
```

It stores all of the coordinates but it even stores the coordinates of the path we do not want to take ((7,2)(8,2)(9,2) and then back to (7,3)). Is there a way that I can store just store the shortest path?

Comment: Something to get you in the right direction: `std::vector` and `std::vector::push_back`.

Comment: Your algorithm looks good in that it should find the shortest path if tweaked appropriately.  I'd agree with chris's suggestion and further suggest that you change the method prototype to something like `std::vector Solve_Maze(int coorx, coory, std::vector path)`.

Comment: Would I have to have two vectors(one for x values and one for y values)? And would this word with the recursion aspect of the problem because if the algorithm is searching a different path then the shortest, the coordinates would also be saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can keep track of the solution coordinates using a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

const int w = 10, l = 10;
const char Start = 'S', Path = ' ', End = 'E', Visited = '.', Solution = '*';

char Map[w][l + 1] =
{
    { "  #  # #  " },
    { " S   #  # " },
    { " ###      " },
    { "   #   #  " },
    { "    #   # " },
    { "#        #" },
    { "    ###   " },
    { "  ##E ##  " },
    { "  #       " },
    { "   ##### #" },
};

int Solved = false;
vector<pair<int,int> > SolutionCoors;

void PrintMap()
{
    int x, y;

    for (y = 0; y < w; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < l; x++)
            cout << Map[y][x];

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Solve_Maze(int CoorX, int CoorY)
{
    if (CoorX >= 0 && CoorX < l && CoorY >= 0 && CoorY < w && !Solved)
    {
        SolutionCoors.push_back(make_pair(CoorX, CoorY)); // Store potential solution

        if (Map[CoorY][CoorX] == Start || Map[CoorY][CoorX] == Path)
        {
            Map[CoorY][CoorX] = Visited;

            Solve_Maze(CoorX + 1, CoorY);
            Solve_Maze(CoorX - 1, CoorY);
            Solve_Maze(CoorX, CoorY + 1);
            Solve_Maze(CoorX, CoorY - 1);
        }
        else if (Map[CoorY][CoorX] == End)
            Solved = true;

        if (!Solved)
            SolutionCoors.pop_back();
    }
}

int main()
{
    PrintMap();

    Solve_Maze(1, 1);

    if (Solved)
    {
        for (vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it = SolutionCoors.begin();
             it != SolutionCoors.end();
             it++)
        {
            cout << "(" << it->first << "," << it->second << ")" << endl; // Print solution coords
            Map[it->second][it->first] = Solution; // Also mark on the map
        }

        PrintMap();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  #  # #  
 S   #  # 
 ###      
   #   #  
    #   # 
#        #
    ###   
  ##E ##  
  #       
   ##### #
(1,1)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,1)
(4,2)
(5,2)
(6,2)
(6,3)
(5,3)
(5,4)
(6,4)
(7,4)
(7,5)
(8,5)
(8,6)
(9,6)
(9,7)
(8,7)
(8,8)
(7,8)
(6,8)
(5,8)
(4,8)
(4,7)
  #  #.#..
 ****#..#.
 ###***...
   #.**#..
    #***#.
#      **#
    ### **
  ##* ##**
  #.*****.
   ##### #
```

Also note that my `Map[][]` has reversed coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make explicit the stack, that now it's implicit in procedure `Solve_Maze` calls, and copy from the stack to solution vector when you reach `Solved=true`, if the length of the current path if less that the length of the previously saved (if any). Of course push `coorx,coory` when entering the procedure, pop them when exiting (don't care about state change).

Other than an external var if type 'stack' (you can use an array, if you don't use std libs), you could tie together coorx,coory in a struct and pass around a pointer to them when allocated into Solve_Maze. But this changes the code a lot: it's far easier to pass around the stack...